# upload file on select file in jquery file upload plugin

Tags: jquery, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

I am using jquery file upload plugin for upload file. I want uploading is start on when user select file from file browser dialog.

How can i do this.

http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: What code have you tried that isn't working? Please add it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can create a function for the "add" callback, as found in the documentation for this plugin, under the "options" section: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#add

So basically, when you create the file uploader, you would include something like this:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: '/path/to/upload/handler.json',
    add: function (e, data) {
        // automatically start upload process
        $('#fileupload').submit();
    };
});
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
url: '/path/to/upload/handler.json',
add: function (e, data) {
              data.submit();
     },
});
```